# How to write a code to find the mode of the ints in the array without using a personally created method ie just regular "raw code"

Tags: java, arrays, mean, median, mode

I'm writing a code to find the mean, median and mode of an array of randomly generated ints (user inputs a size for the array and a range between which random numbers are to be generated it generate numbers between 3-22 randomly. I have not had too much trouble writing code for a mean or median but I cannot seem to be able to write code to calculate the mode (most commonly occurring number). Can anyone help or show/put code for how to calculate the mode of a randomly generated array of ints without having to create a method for yourself in the code? Thanks. Here is what I have so far (code that finds the mean and median):

```
    public class ArraysIntsMeanMedianAndMode {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int ArraySize;
    int min;
    int max;
    double x;
    // To get the Size and range of numbers for the randomly genereated ints in the array.
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What size should the array be?");
    ArraySize = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a minimum value for the range of ints.");
    min = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter a maximum value for the range of ints.");
    max = sc.nextInt();
    //Making the array and filling it based on the user inputs
    int[] MMMarray = new int[ArraySize];
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ArraySize; i++) {
        x = (int) (Math.random() * ((max - min) + 1)) + min;
        System.out.println(x);
        int RandoNums = (int) x;
        total = total + RandoNums;
        MMMarray[i] = RandoNums;
    }
    //Finding mean/average
    double Mean = (total + 0.0) / ArraySize;
    System.out.println("The mean is: " + Mean);
    //Finding Median/Middle number
    Arrays.sort(MMMarray);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(MMMarray));
    if (ArraySize % 2 == 0) {
        System.out.println("The median is: " + ((MMMarray[(ArraySize / 2)] + 0.0) + MMMarray[(ArraySize / 2) - 1]) / 2 + ".");
    } else System.out.println("The median is: " + MMMarray[ArraySize / 2] + ".");
    //How to find mode????????
```

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but why do you absolutely want to avoid creating a method for this (and for finding the average and median) ?

Comment: If the numbers are between 3 and 22, why not declare an array of size 20, set each number to 0, and then whenever you encounter a number n in the data set, ++ the entry in slot n-3 in the array. When you're done, find the index of the maximum element(s) in that array, add 3, and you're done.

Comment: Oh, if you're sorting the array of numbers anyway, you just need to find the longest run.

Comment: Or if its not an array homework, you could use java streams with groupBy and find the key with the max number of valus in the resulting map

Comment: see http://www.skylit.com/beprepared/x2009a1.html for how to find the longest run once the array is sorted. If your data is bimodal and you want to report both modes, you might need to make another pass over the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding mode of unsorted array of int:

```
int freq = 0;
int value = 0;
int length = MMMArray.length;

for (int outer = 0; outer < length; outer++)
{
    int tempFreq = 0;

    for (int inner = 0; inner < length; inner++)
    {
        if (MMMArray[outer] == MMMArray[inner])
        {
            tempFreq++;
        }
    }

    if (tempFreq > freq)
    {
        freq = tempFreq;
        value = MMMArray[outer];
    }
}

System.out.println("Mode is " + value + ", which appears " + freq + " times.");
```

Comment: wouldn't it suffice to say for( int inner=outer?

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, this is fantastic and works perfectly, you're a godsend!!!!

Comment: @JeremyKahan You  know what? It would suffice. It's a nice little optimization to avoid comparing elements that have already been compared. I knew the general strategy and wrote this off the top of my head, but that's a nice improvement.

Comment: Thanks. I still feel like since the array is actually sorted anyway to find the median, one need not do the above (which is O(n^2), I believe) as opposed to finding the longest run (which is O(n)). [granted needing the sort makes the whole thing O(n log n)]. But the person who asked the question is ecstatic, so I won't quibble.

Comment: @JeremyKahan I provided a solution that was independent of sorting because you already linked the simpler solution based on run length. I figure OP could crib from that link if he wanted. I could incorporate a "sorted" solution in this answer. Maybe I have too much faith that people actually read comments just because I do it. myself.

Comment: Well, I read this comment. That makes sense to me. I felt I couldn't just post the code of the Litvins (even though I had to write something similar last week because AP CS A practice on loops had it -- but theirs was cleaner than mine).

Answer (score 0):

Because you have already sorted the array to calculate the median, the problem of finding the mode(s) becomes equivalent to finding the longest consecutive streak of the same number. So, for example, if you have [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 21], there are three consecutive 2's, which is longer than any other run, so 2 is the mode.

To find the longest run, you can pass over the data once more, not reading any element twice. I'm adapting the code of [Litvin and Litvin](http://www.skylit.com/beprepared/x2009a1.html) ever so slightly to use your array name, to count a run of 1 as a run, and to report what number the mode is rather than where it is in the array. You can drop this code in right where you ask your question, after the median has been calculated.

```
 // at this point MMMArray is a sorted, nonempty array of int, because it was already sorted to find the median
int maxRunStart = 0, maxRunLength = 1;
int runStart = 0, runLength = 1;

for (int i = 1; i <= MMMArray.length; i++) //what they do here by using <= 

//rather than < is worth reflecting upon
//it handles the case of the biggest run being at the end within the loop body
    {
      if (i < MMMArray.length && MMMArray[i] == MMMArray[i - 1])//notice how the boolean short-circuit prevents reading beyond the end of the array
      {
        runLength++;
      }
      else
      {
        if (runLength > maxRunLength)
        {
          maxRunStart = runStart;
          maxRunLength = runLength;
        }
        runStart = i;
        runLength = 1;
      }
    }
      System.out.println("The mode is: " + MMMArray[maxRunStart] + ".");
    }
```

Now here is something new to ponder. Suppose MMMArray contains [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]. This code (or that of MarsAtomic) will report 1 is the only mode. But the data is bimodal, and 3 is the mode as much as 1 is. One way to adapt the code would be to store the mode(s) in an array list (or an array, because we know up front there cannot be more modes than numbers). I think it is simpler (not more efficient, just easier not to mess up and without introducing another non-simple type) to make one more pass over the data. If you want that, then after the first for loop, instead of the println of the one mode, insert the following:

```
runLength = 1;
runStart = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= MMMArray.length; i++)
{
  if (i < MMMArray.length && MMMArray[i] == MMMArray[i - 1])
  {
    runLength++;
  }
  else
  {
    if (runLength == maxRunLength)
    {
        System.out.println("The mode is: " + MMMArray[runStart] + ".");
    }
    runStart = i;
    runLength = 1;
  }
}
```